# Help understanding why absolute value of denominator doesn't change normal ratio distribution

Tags: probability

It is well known that the ratio distribution $X/Y$ of standard normal random variables $X,Y$ is the standard Cauchy distribution.

Interestingly though, the random variable $X/|Y|$ is also a standard Cauchy distribution.

My instinct tells me this is because:

1. The absolute value doesn't affect the range of values $X/Y$ takes
2. The density weighting on values $X/Y$ can take is unaffected since there is half the number of ways to get each value $z=x/y$, while the density of $Y$ is doubled, being a half-normal distribution.

I'm wondering if someone can explain this to me in a more formal way. I'm not looking for a proof, just want to understand why the absolute value doesn't change the distribution.

Comment: Previous discussion of the problem:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477420/distribution-of-y-fracx-1x-2?rq=1, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330607/distribution-of-the-ratio-of-two-i-i-d-standard-normals. There is an assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independently distributed, which you do not mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a standard normal r.v. $X\sim N(0,1)$ as $X=\sigma |X|$, where $\sigma$ is uniformly distributed on $\{-1,1\}$ and independent of $X$.  (This is
because the distribution of $X$ is symmetric.)  Similarly for $Y=\tau |Y|$, where $\tau$ has the same distribution as $\sigma$, and all of $\sigma,\tau,|X|$ and $|Y|$ are independent.  Now your ratio $R = X/Y = (\sigma / \tau) (|X|/|Y|)$, and since $\sigma / \tau$ has the same distribution as $\sigma$, it should be clear that all the quantities $R, |X|/Y, X/|Y|, \sigma |R|$ have the same distribution.